# Как исправить логику в Cinemachine Confiner?

Tags: unity3d

При добавлении PolygonCollider2D в Cinemachine Confiner, для того, что бы ограничить видимость левой стороны, персонаж двигается только в пределах PolygonCollider2D. При выходе из коллайдера - камера не начинает двигаться.